# Get objects instead of array from MongoDB cursor

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I use a query builder to get all my documents from MongoDB and it return a cursor

```
// My repository
public function messages()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->field('sendAt')
        ->sort('ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();

    return $qb;
}
```

I can get an array of the first document found using this

```
//My controller
$qb = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Messages')
    ->messages();

$qb->next();
$qb->current();
```

There is a way to get object instead of array from cursor ?

Maybe I should convert this array ?

**EDIT :**

cf : [Symfony QueryBuilder returning MongoDB cursor instead of objects array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566009/symfony-querybuilder-returning-mongodb-cursor-instead-of-objects-array)

```
// My repository
public function messages()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->eagerCursor(true)
        ->field('sendAt')
        ->sort('ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();

    return $qb;
}
```

`eagerCursor(true)` solve the issue.

Comment: Make `foreach` on cursor, and you'll have objects.

Comment: This is still returning me arrays for each documents found

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566009/symfony-querybuilder-returning-mongodb-cursor-instead-of-objects-array

Comment: Yes i think, this post solve my issue, thanks anyway

Comment: no problem. good luck!